# Can't Get Inner Exception for "The type initializer for 'System.Web.UI.BaseParser' threw an exception."

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a WebApi 2 service setup.  It has been working beautifully.

But I have done something (that I can't seem to figure out) to cause it to give the following exception page when I browse to index.html or to any of my service actions:

> Parser Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: The type initializer for 'System.Web.UI.BaseParser' threw an exception.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="WebHost.WebApiApplication" Language="C#" %>

Even thought I am running in the debugger, Visual Studio does not break out of execution (like the exception is being caught and thrown away).

I have put a break point on the first line in Global.asax.cs's `Application_Start()` and it is not hit.

I don't know how that screen is generated, so I don't know how to see the inner exception to see what is really going wrong.

**Any ideas on what is wrong or how I can see the inner exception?**

Comment: First thing's first, do you have all your exceptions set to "Break When Thrown?" Press Ctrl+Alt+E in Visual Studio, and make sure that Common Language Runtime Exceptions is checked

Comment: @2-bits - I did turn on all Common Languange Runtime Exceptions.  But it never broke on anything.  Must have been a glitch.  When I restarted Visual Studio, the error would not repro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted Visual Studio and that fixed it....